# Why gradle build shows odd behaviour with sdk version 28?

Tags: android, gradle

After installing android studio on my new PC I couldn't build any project with target SDK version 28.0.0. But it shows no error with 27.1.1. So I am using this older SDK version to build. I have also found an answer on different context on stack-overflow stating that 28.0.0 version spits out a bunch of errors. But why?

I have tried clean build, invalidating the cache and deleting .gradle folder But nothing worked and could not find any solution.

How can I make a successful build with the latest version of SDK?

As mentioned in comments updating with error texts:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  W/ResourceType( 5112): ResTable_package:unknown data size 0x20202020 extends beyond resource end 00170544.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:149: error: resource android:color/black not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:151: error: resource android:color/black not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:152: error: resource android:color/black not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:159: error: resource android:color/white not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:170: error: resource android:color/white not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:171: error: resource android:color/black not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:186: error: resource android:color/white not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:188: error: resource android:color/black not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:189: error: resource android:color/white not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:218: error: resource android:color/white not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:219: error: resource android:color/black not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:241: error: resource android:color/black not found.
error: resource android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2569: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowSwipeToDismiss' not found.
error: resource android:style/Widget not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2572: error: style attribute 'android:attr/layout' not found.
error: resource android:style/Animation not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2581: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found.
C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2582: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found.
error: resource android:style/Animation not found.

Command: C:\Users\ThisUser\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\39c8269e0849c64d409f0ab7dabfbbb8\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\ThisUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.fitasc.ThisTestGame\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\ThisUser\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisTestGame\wear\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

The emphasize is not in these errors because these are not present when used with other SDK versions, for both wear and mobile build, these errors showing with SDK version of 28.0.0.

Thanks.

Comment: it cannot find the theme ...

Comment: It can find theme and everything works if the sdk version is 27.1.1 :)

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: Updated. Note: no error happens with other versions of sdk build targets but with 28.0.0. I thought these not really errors so I dont need to add them. Need a solution to work with latest version of sdk build target.

Comment: What library versions are you using? For support lib, material design, app compat etc... It looks like the new SDK removed some android attributes. Perhaps if you update your dependencies versions to 28.x.x they will compile.

Comment: @Izabela It can be. What dependencies? It's same with a completely new project.

Comment: It was solved after removing platform tools folder and cache and re-downloading them.